# Threading in .net

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a simple example of a winforms application where i choose a directory in a directory  chooser and click a button to loop through the directory and copy each file in the directory into another directory.

i want to do the file copy on a background thread to avoid locking the GUI.

i am looking for the simplest solution to:

1. Create the background thread
2. Pass the source and destinations in
3. Get a callback on progress so i can show a progress bar on the GUI thread

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend using the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(VS.80).aspx) class.

[Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answer, I'd add that the BackgroundWorker is ideal for this as it can give you progress updates too. Just make sure you prevent reentry - that is you need to prevent the situation where the user could start the background worker again before it has completed.