# Putting a section of code on a different thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I appreciate your help ahead of time.  I'm fairly new to programming, so go easy on me.  Right now I have a time-consuming loop which I really need to run outside of the UI thread, because Update() updates a progress bar, which isn't happening till this loop is done.  I've looked at some short threading tutorials, and they the updates never render until the big loop is finished.

```
private void Button_Convert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 MachineAngleCalculations.Instance.Arm1Length_Arbitrary = 12;
 MachineAngleCalculations.Instance.Arm2Length_Arbitrary = 11;

 int resolution = 100000; //points per shape
 double xstep, ystep, x, y;

 int totalpoints = resolution * ShapeList.Count;
 int calculatedpoints = 0;
 ProgStat.Update(calculatedpoints, totalpoints, "Calculated", "individual instructions.");

 InstructionList.Clear();

 foreach (MachineLine item in ShapeList)
 {
  xstep = (item.End.X - item.Start.X) / (resolution - 1);
  ystep = (item.End.Y - item.Start.Y) / (resolution - 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < resolution; i++)
  {
   x = item.Start.X + xstep * i;
   y = item.Start.Y + ystep * i;
   InstructionList.Add(MachineAngleCalculations.Instance.XYtoMachineInstrution(x, y, 1));
   calculatedpoints += 1;
   ProgStat.Update(calculatedpoints, totalpoints, "Calculated", "individual instructions.");
  }
 }
}
```

So what is the simplest way to execute the `foreach` loop on a different thread?
Is there a way to do so without putting it in a different function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670510/threading-in-net

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

Aynchronous Programming

[Asynchronous Method Invocation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AsyncMethodInvocation.aspx) (Best tutorial ever!!)

Background Worker

[BackgroundWorker Class Sample for Beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/BackgroundWorker_sample.aspx)

Comment: What is "MethodInvoker" in this tutorial?  He references it 16 times, and never defines it even once.

Comment: Its a special delegate that can be use to call a function which has no parameter and return type is void.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution will be using BackgroundWorker Class

Comment: Can you show how to do that without having to put it in a new function?

Comment: @Adam S - Are you using a weird compiler where you have to pay for each function you define? :-P

Comment: The reason I want to avoid this is because if it's in a separate function, that function won't have access to the variables defined in Button_Convert_Click.